# Django - User Geolocation

Tags: python, django, geolocation

Currently developing a web application with Django 1.8 and would like to be able to show the city, country and postal code without being entered by the user to register, please could someone help me on this?

Thank You.

Comment: Have a look into [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/), with GeoIP [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/)

Comment: I tried using GeoIP but does not work with private IP @Pynchia

Comment: of course it doesn't! ;D

Comment: Well, I try to find a little more general solution @Pynchia

Comment: let me know if you find one!!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement this using HTML5 and Google Maps APIs.

1. Using the [HTML5 Geolocation APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation), you'll get user's location coordinates.
2. Using coordinates and [Google Maps API for reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse), you'll get user's full address.

Example implementation -

```
function checkLocation() {
    //geolocation API options
    var options =  {
        maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000};
    //success getting the geolocation
    function success(ppos) {
        lat = ppos.coords.latitude;
        lng = ppos.coords.longitude;
        codeLatLng(lat, lng);
    }
    //error when getting the geolocation 
    function error(err) {
        var errorMessage = "Error:";
        switch(err.code) {
            case err.TIMEOUT:
            errorMessage = 'Error: Attempts to retrieve location timed out.';
            break;
            case err.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            errorMessage = "Error: Your browser doesn't know where you are.";
            break;
            case err.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            errorMessage = 'Error: You have to give us permission!';
            break;
            case err.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            errorMessage = 'Error: Unknown error returned.';
            break;
            default:
            errorMessage = 'Error: ' + err + ' ' + err.code;
        }
    }
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    }
}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var lat = parseFloat(lat);
    var lng = parseFloat(lng);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                return results[1].formatted_address;
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I think this solution can give you Country and City but I don't think it'll give you the postal code.

Comment: It can give postal code also but only where it is available. That is most of the countries. Two downsides of using the Google Geolocation API are 1. The user has to agree to share the location with you and 2. It is somehow inconsistent in naming things. Locality, sublocality, administrative_area_level_X mean different things for different countries. It needs some thinking and some trial and error for consistency.

Comment: How to save the location in `DataBase` ?